# Subset sum of P elements (with repetition allowed) divisible by M

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Given an array **A** of **N** elements. We need to find the number of subsets (with **repetition** of numbers allowed) such that the number of elements in the subset is P and the sum of those P elements is divisible by **M**.

N can be upto **10^5**

P can be upto **10^5**

M can be upto **10**

Elements in the array can be upto **10^9**

What I thought: I thought of generating subset sum using dynamic programming starting from sum=M till sum=P*max(A) and then find all the subset sums which are divisible by M but it will surely be too unefficient. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Subset sum (with repetition allowed) algorithm can be seen here: https://tutorialspoint.dev/algorithm/dynamic-programming-algorithms/ways-sum-n-using-array-elements-repetition-allowed

Even small hints about the approach would be appreciated

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in your post. You have a problem, which looks like "homework" and you want someone to write the code for you? If so, that's not what StackOverflow is for. Check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JoãoSoares I don't want any code. Just an approach or hint to how to solve the problem efficiently would do.

Comment: I understand, but that's not what StackOverflow is for. Check the link I sent you above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Usually in this kind of problems it's a good approach to check the constraints. One that gets the attention is the constraint for the variable M (up to 10). That means you can work with modular arithmetic and find the number of subset sums of size P that have a remainder 0 with M.